# How did Princess Bubblegum know her pink laser thing would hold the Empress in Stakes?

Tags: adventure-time

In the episode "Adventure Time Stakes", how did Princess Bubblegum know her pink laser thing would hold The Empress in Stakes?

I get she's a scientist with cool technology or whatever but how did she know her laser thing would actually be able to hold such a vampire?